# How do I validate that all textboxes have unique text before insert?

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-core, razor, foreach

I have a table where I am inserting as bulk

```
//table start for each loop 

<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].ItemName, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].StartDate, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].EndDate, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
</tr>
```

How do I ensure that all the boxes have different unique text using jQuery. I want to ensure the `itemname` `start` and `end` date for each row is different? The start date and end date on the same row can be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do like this.When one row data is not unique,it will add errormessage to a `string`:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            var ItemNames = new Array();
            var StartDates = new Array();
            var EndDates = new Array();
            var errormessage="";
            $("tbody tr").each(function (index, item) {
                var ItemName = $(this).find("td input[name*='ItemName']").val();
                var StartDate = $(this).find("td input[name*='StartDate']").val();
                var EndDate = $(this).find("td input[name*='EndDate']").val();
                if (ItemNames.includes(ItemName) || StartDates.includes(StartDate) || EndDates.includes(EndDate)) {
                    errormessage+= "data of row " + (index+1) + " is not unique.";
                } else {
                    ItemNames.push(ItemName);
                    StartDates.push(StartDate);
                    EndDates.push(EndDate);

                }
            });
            alert(errormessage);
        })
    </script>
```